Google Password Manager - Login credentials for any URL ending with paths like /user/login or /admin
I need to set up Google Password Manager so that it offers login credentials for any URL ending with paths like /user/login or /admin, regardless of the domain.
This should apply universally across different websites like abc.com or xyz.com.
